# Override jQuery Mobile's default back button behaviour, then restore it

Tags: jquery, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I have a page in my site that list recipes, and another that details a recipe. What I would like to do is merge those two pages into one, and when a recipe is selected from the list, have the list fade out and have the recipe animate in.

When a recipe's details are displayed, I would like to override the back button click handler to animate out the details, and fade in the recipe list. Once that transition has completed, I would like JQM's default back button behaviour to be restored.

I can manage the transition between list and details easily enough, but does anyone know how I can fiddle with the back button handler without breaking things for the rest of the site?

Regards,

Chris

**UPDATE**

And by back button, I mean the browser's back button, or the hardware back button on Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to capture `touchstart` event and use `e.preventDefault()` on it.

Comment: I'm unsure I understand how touchstart could be used with the browser's back button.

Comment: If you'll add your listener to back button, which will preventDefault event, jQuery's event for tap might not be called.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to select the browser's back button. You can select the back button JQM generates, but the the browser's back button doesn't exist in the DOM.

Comment: I thought you're talking about DOM back button. You'll need to create a page with custom transition so that jQuery Mobile adds history entry to browser.